# MATLAB - mex file setup error

Tags: matlab, mex

I am new to MATLAB and I have started coding using this platform. Currently, I am facing a problem with the creation of the MEX- file. I have added the required add-on (MinGW) and it was installed successfully. But when I tried the function mex -setup, I got an error stating that :

> MEX configured to use 'MinGW64 Compiler (C)' for C language
>   compilation. Warning: The MATLAB C and Fortran API has changed to
>   support MATLAB     variables with more than 2^32-1 elements. You will be
>   required   to update your code to utilize the new API.     You can find
>   more information about this at:
>   http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/upgrading-mex-files-to-use-64-bit-api.html.
>
> To choose a different language, select one from the following:  mex
>   -setup C++   mex -setup FORTRAN

I am just not able to understand how to proceed further from this point.

I am new to programing and therefore it would be so so much helpful if someone can give me some tips or idea on how to proceed from here?  Or if someone faced a similar situation and got it solved, it would be really helpful if you can share the steps.

Comment: It seems like MinGW64 was successfully setup as a compiler. That warning is something to keep in mind when you write code in C++, it's not an error. I recommend compiling sample files which should be in the `matlabroot\extern\examples\mex` directory.

Comment: There is no problem here. There is nothing to solve. That statement says that everything is OK.